# Keep a MenuItem's IsChecked property synced with a bool

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a simple WPF Application that has a menu on top. I want to add an option to make the main window to stay on top of other windows.

I created a bool named setTopMost in Property > Settings tab for users to save this setting. So, the setting will be remembered even after the app is terminated.

Everything is working as intended, I can click on the option or use the shortcut of Ctrl+T to make the window to stay on top, but I cannot get a check mark to appear next to the option when the window is on top of other windows.

I've read several articles regarding binding IsChecked to a bool, but I could not solve this problem on my own.

Here are my codes.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+T" Command="{Binding TopMostCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<MenuItem Header="_Options">
    <MenuItem x:Name="Menu_AlwaysOnTop" Header="Always On _Top" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding isTopMost}" Command="{Binding TopMostCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+T" />
</MenuItem>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WPF_Practice
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public bool isTopMost;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new PracticeDataContext();
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isTopMost = Properties.Settings.Default.setTopMost;
            Topmost = Properties.Settings.Default.setTopMost;
        }
    }

    public class PracticeDataContext
    {
        public ICommand TopMostCommand { get; } = new TopMostCommand();
    }

    public class TopMostCommand : ICommand
    {
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var TopMostClass = new MainWindow();
            TopMostClass.WindowTopMost();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

}
```

Please mind that I am doing this as a hobby and quite new to this.

Comment: binding only works on get/set `Property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why your `MenuItem` isn't updating properly is because you set the `DataContext` of the `Window` to `PracticeDataContext`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new PracticeDataContext(); <--
}
```

This means that your bindings in `MainWindow.xaml` are going to be looking for properties in `PracticeDataContext`.

In this case you would want to have an `IsTopMost` property in your `PracticeDataContext` class in order for the binding to work.

Since `IsTopMost` isn't set until the `Loaded` event handler fires, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `PracticeDataContext` class so that your `IsTopMost` binding will get notified when it is set from settings.

A quick search on `INotifyPropertyChanged` will show you lots of examples. It's pretty easy.